# Convert Raw SQL 'NOT' IN (too slow) to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a running script using Raw SQL in Laravel 5.3 controller which I found it slow and not secure ( as Raw ). If there any way to make it more effecient and convert it to eloquent or Query Builder for Laravel ?

code as below & Thanks !

```
SELECT  machine_code, machine_name
FROM    factory_equipment
WHERE  machine_code  NOT IN
    (
        SELECT  distinct(machine_code)
        FROM    echecklist_data
        WHERE   DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() 
    )
  AND type='production' ORDER BY machine_code ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working using laravel's query. Hope it helps others

```
DB::table('factory_equipment')
        ->select('factory_equipment.machine_code', 'factory_equipment.machine_name')
        ->leftjoin('echecklist_data', function ($leftjoin) {
            $leftjoin->on('factory_equipment.machine_code', '=', 'echecklist_data.machine_code')
            ->Where( DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(echecklist_data.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), DB::raw("CURDATE()") );
            })
        ->where('factory_equipment.type' , '=', 'production') 
        ->whereNull('echecklist_data.machine_code')         
        ->get();
```

Comment: I'm glad to see you got it worked out; sorry I wasn't able to help beyond the raw SQL. You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it more efficient using SQL.  I would recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT fe.machine_code, fe.machine_name
FROM factory_equipment fe
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM echecklist_data ed
                  WHERE ed.machine_code = fe.machine_code AND
                        ed.date >= CURDATE() AND
                        ed.date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                 ) AND
     fe.type = 'production'
ORDER BY fe.machine_code ASC;
```

I would further recommend indexes on:  `factory_equipment(type, machine_code, machine_name)` and `echecklist_data(machine_code, date)`.

Comment: thanks ! is there any way to convert it to laravel eloquent which I am not good at ?

Comment: @Wahsei . . . Neither am I.

Answer (score 3):

You can speed up this query by making it into a `LEFT JOIN` and selecting only rows which have no match in the `echecklist_data` table:

```
SELECT    fe.machine_code, fe.machine_name
FROM      factory_equipment fe
LEFT JOIN echecklist_data ed ON ed.machine_code = fe.machine_code AND DATE_FORMAT(ed.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
WHERE     fe.type='production' AND ed.machine_code IS NULL
ORDER BY  fe.machine_code ASC
```

Note that if your `date` column is a `DATETIME` type, then using `DATE(ed.date) = CURDATE()` will also be more efficient than `DATE_FORMAT(ed.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()`.

Comment: thanks ! I will compare both query later. Is there any way to convert it to laravel eloquent which I am not good at ?

Comment: I'm not good at that either I'm afraid... but it's unlikely to be any more efficient in eloquent than it is as a raw query.

Comment: @Wahsei You should also note what GordonLinoff says about using indexes. And his code for checking the date may well be faster than using `DATE(date)`